# Laravel How to join table and merge columns, then set a 'LIKE' query on Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

**ENV:**

`Laravel 5.7.28`

Database `mysql`

`CentOS 7.2`

I have 3 table like as below, I need join this 3 table and merge columns
(`customer.first_name,customer.last_name,customer.address,job.name,job.address,job.date`)
 to set 'like' query.

For example,
After coulms merge `customer.first_name,customer.last_name,customer.address,job.name,job.address,job.date`
customer.first_name + customer.last_name + customer.address + job.name + job.address +job.date
is
'TOMSMITHCecilia ChapmanABC.LtdIris Watson2019-01-10', so

```
 when $text = 'MS';
set  'like' '%'.$text.'%' will return below result


customer.first_name = TOM

customer.last_name = SMITH

customer.address = Cecilia Chapman

job.name = ABC.Ltd

job.address = Iris Watson

job.date = 2019-01-10
```

1. id table (relation belongs To table customer and job)

   - id
   - customer_id
   - job_id
2. customer table

   - id
   - first_name
   - last_name
   - address
3. job id

   - id
   - name
   - address
   - job_date

Comment: Did you try something first? If yes please show the code.

Answer (score 2):

See this

```
\DB::table('id')->join('customer','customer.customer_id','id.customer_id')
->join('job','job.id','id.job_id')
->where('customer.first_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $text . '%')
->orWhere('customer.last_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $text . '%')
->orWhere('customer.address', 'LIKE', '%' . $text . '%')
->orWhere('job.name', 'LIKE', '%' . $text . '%')
->orWhere('job.address', 'LIKE', '%' . $text . '%')
->get();
```

Comment: I need join this 3 table and merge columns (customer.first_name,customer.last_name,customer.address,job.name,job.address,job.date) to set 'like' query. not set or where.
 my example is first_name + last_name = TOMSMITH So when $text = 'MS'; set 'like' '%'.$text.'%' can return blow (merge customer.first_name and customer.last_name) will so example result

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple where condition then you may use where function with orWhere like this:

```
\DB::table('id')->join('customer','customer.customer_id','id.customer_id')
->join('job','job.id','id.job_id')
->where(function ($query) use($text) {
                $query->where('customer.first_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $text .'%')
                      ->orWhere('customer.last_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $text . '%')
                      ->orWhere('customer.address', 'LIKE', '%' . $text . '%')
                      ->orWhere('job.name', 'LIKE', '%' . $text . '%')
                      ->orWhere('job.address', 'LIKE', '%' . $text . '%')
            })->get();
```

Comment: I need join this 3 table and merge columns (customer.first_name,customer.last_name,customer.address,job.name,job.address,job.date) to set 'like' query.
not set or where
my example is first_name + last_name = TOMSMITH

So  when $text = 'MS';
set  'like' '%'.$text.'%' can return blow (merge customer.first_name and customer.last_name) will so example result